# Regex working but printing an empty output file

Tags: python, regex

i am using

```
(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}[a-zA-Z]?)
```

to define my regex, i know it pulls the correct information out of a string based on a regex builder. However i am trying to read a full text file and it is not printing the results to an additional file, it comes back blank. The text file has multiple strings along the lines of:

P:\DBI_rescans\11-06-2722A.pdf

and i need to pull out and print to a file just the 11-06-2722A portion.

Here is the full code:

```
import re
filepath = r'filepath'
regex = r"(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}[a-zA-Z]?)"
compiled_re = re.compile(regex)
with open('P.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open ("PCN.txt","w") as p:
        for line in f:
            match = compiled_re.match(line)
            if match:
                print(f"{match.group(1)}", file=p)
```

i am not entirely sure where i went wrong as to not have it print to a file

Comment: You have to use `match = compiled_re.search(line)` instead of `match` because match starts at the beginning of the string which is not the case for the date.

Answer (score 0):

Matching is just testing if the pattern *matches*, not capturing or extracting groups.

#### Extract pattern using `re.findall`

Use the method `re.findall` to find and extract the group for each line.

```
import re

file_contents = r'''
Hello World
P:\DBI_rescans\11-06-2722A.pdf
P:\DBI_rescans\some.txt
'''

def extract_pattern_from(text):
    results = []
    regex = r"(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}[a-zA-Z]?)"
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    for line in text.split('\n'):
        print(f"Finding in '{line}' ..")
        found = pattern.findall(line)
        if found:
            print(f"Found pattern '{found}'")
            results += found
    return results


extracted = extract_pattern_from(file_contents)
print(f"Extracted: {extracted}")
```

#### Write extracted items to file

Use the method to filter the pattern from your input file and `write` the extracted list to your output file:

```
with open('P.txt', 'r') as in:
    file_contents = in.read()
    extracted = extract_pattern_from(file_contents)
    if extracted:
        with open ("PCN.txt","w") as out:
            out.writelines(extracted)
```